# How to add a cookie or local storage to my popup on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, popup, local-storage

I added a popup to my website but it's getting really irritating for it to popup on each page reload.

I watched some videos on how to add a cookie but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

The popup must only appear once a day per user, i'm also open to try local storage

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class='popup' id="consent-popup">
        <div class='cnt223'>
            <div class="popupCloseButton">&times;</div>
            <h1 style="font-size: 18px;">Mholweni, Hello, Goeie dag!</h1>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">We respect your rights. Please read our Usage Agreement <a href="https://www.saonline.africa/use.html" target="_blank" style="color: #1b305c !important; font-weight: 300;"><u>HERE</u></a>.</p>
            <div class="popupAcceptButton"><font style="font-size: 15px;">I ACCEPT AND WANT TO PROCEED</font></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function(){
        var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        overlay.show();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popup').show();
        $('.popupCloseButton').click(function(){
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
        }); 
         
        $('.x').click(function(){
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
        }); 
        $('.popupAcceptButton').click(function(){
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
        }); 
         
        $('.x').click(function(){
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
        });
        });
       
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using localStorage you can achieve what you want with something like this. You save the day the popup last appeared and if it's different to today show the popup again and set the new date.

```
const datesAreOnSameDay = (first, second) =>
  first.getFullYear() === second.getFullYear() &&
  first.getMonth() === second.getMonth() &&
  first.getDate() === second.getDate();

const date = new Date();

const lastDateShown = localStorage.getItem('popup-appeared')
if(!lastDateShown || !datesAreOnSameDay(date, new Date(lastDateShown))) {
  localStorage.setItem('popup-appeared', date)
  // Display popup
}
```

Comment: Would I have to type in a date every day??

Comment: No! `new Date()` returns todays date automatically. So if a user visits the site and gets the popup we will save todays date in localStorage. If the users visits again the same day, the date will be the same day as the one we saved in localStorage and we will not do anything. If the user visits any other day the two dates will differ and we can show the popup again and save the new date in localStorage.